# Get current user newsfeed along with post author picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to obtain all newsfeed posts of the current user along with each post author picture url in a single query, but I cannot succeed.

I can get current user newfeed by calling "/me/home" in Graph Api, and I can get a specific user picture by calling "{user_id}/picture". How can I get every post author picture of my newsfeed in one single query?

Thanks in advance!
Pablo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use field expansion to get at this. The one complicating factor is you will have to manually request all the fields you need now. Try this query:

```
me/home?fields=from.name,from.picture,message,picture
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy actually. Use the `/me/home` query as you have been. But instead of makin a call to `/user_id/picture` you can just do this in HTML:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?type=square" />
```

E.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square

Comment: But doing it that way I have to make a call for each post author, and what I would want to do is to make just one call where the result is my newsfeed including the picture of every author of every post in my newsfeed.

Comment: You don't need to get the picture in the API call. If you know the author's user_id (which you do from the first call), you just need to reference the image without the use of the API. Read my answer again. I'm not calling the API again - I am simply getting the image from the API, which you will need to do in the end anyway.

Comment: This method is actually easier because you reduce the response data sent and requested from Facebook to achieve the same functionality.